# What is the proper way to initialize const containers with different values?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, constants

I have some container `struct` that holds a set of configuration elements.

```
struct config
{
    const std::vector<int> config_items;
    const std::vector<double> another_items;
}
```

Also, I have a "container of containers" that should hold a known and limited number of instances of those configuration containers (e.g. 3). Each `config` instance should then have different `int`s and `double`s in the corresponding `vector`s.

```
struct setup
{
    const std::vector<config> items;
}
```

All the `vector`s' items should be `const`, because they should be defined once and never change.

Since the `vector`s are `const`, I can only initialize them in the constructor initializer list. But I want to have multiple instances with different values.

I could create some child `struct`s to create each configuration in the child constructors. But this doesn't work, because I cannot initialize a parent member in the child constructor:

```
struct config_1 : public config
{
    config_1() : config_items { 1, 2 }, another_items { 1.0, 2.0 } {} // Doesn't work
}
```

This seems to be a very poor decision too (remove `const`, make copies...):

```
struct config
{
    std::vector<int> config_items;    
    std::vector<double> another_items;    
}

struct setup
{
    std::vector<config> items;
}

void init()
{
    config c;
    c.config_items = { 1, 2 };
    c.another_items = { 1.0, 2.0 };

    setup s;
    s.items = { c };
}
```

I cannot make a single initializer-list constructor too, because I have multiple `vector`s:

```
struct config
{
    config(std::initializer_list<int> i, std::initializer_list<double> d); // No go
    std::vector<int> config_items;    
    std::vector<double> another_items;    
}
```

Background: I want to have a hardcoded `const` config structure (probably placed in the DATA section or even in the flash memory) for my embedded application. No need to read things from any config files etc.

So my question is: what would you suggest me how I should create such a `const` configuration container?

---

## EDIT

The `std::vector`s are actually wrong here. I'm using a custom container that holds the data in the instance like `std::array` and not like `std::vector` which allocates the storage on the heap.

So the environment should rather look like this:

```
struct config
{
    const std::array<int, 2> config_items;
    const std::array<double, 2> another_items;
}

struct setup
{
    const std::array<config, 3> items;
}
```

Comment: [FYI] vectors are dynamic so they need to be initialized at run time.  If you want static data then you should consider using `std::array`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks for this advice. `vector`s are only for simplicity here, we're using our own templated containers with internal data storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've decided to answer my own question.

As **NathanOliver** and **nwp** mentioned, the `std::vector`s used in question allocate the memory on the heap. Actually, I'm using a custom container similar to an `std::array` that holds the data in the instance itself.

So I should have written something like this in the question:

```
struct config
{
    const std::array<int, 2> config_items;
    const std::array<double, 2> another_items;
}

struct setup
{
    const std::array<config, 3> items;
}
```

Now, since these `struct`s are [PODs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType), I can use an [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of them:

```
setup instance
{
    // std::array c++11-ish double-braces aggregate initialization
    // this is the items member
    { {
        {
            // this is the config_items member
            { { 1, 2 } },

            // this is the another_items member
            { { 1.0, 2.0 } },
        },

        {
            { { 3, 4 } },
            { { 3.0, 4.0 } },
        },

        {
            { { 5, 6 } },
            { { 5.0, 6.0 } },
        }
    } }
};
```

Now, I have an initialized `instance` struct whose members are `const`, and there is no run-time code to do initialization (no ctors, no method calls) but rather the raw data will be directly stored in the DATA section (by default). This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

maybe simply just use a construction like this?

```
struct config
{
    const std::vector<int> _a;
    config(const std::vector<int> &a): _a(a) {}
};
```

later somewhere in a code:

```
config c1({1, 2, 3});
config c2({3, 4, 5, 6});
```

alright, let's get full sample:

```
    struct config
    {
        const std::vector<int> _items;
        config(const std::vector<int> &items): _items(items) {}
    };
    std::vector<config> settings;
    settings.emplace_back(config({1, 2}));
    settings.emplace_back(config({3, 4}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
struct config
{
    const std::vector<int> config_items = []{
        std::vector<int> retval;
        //put whatever stuff you want in retval
        return retval;
    }();
}
```

An optimizing compiler should optimize the lambda away and just put the appropriate values into the vector, depending on how complicated you make it and how many functions you call, but you should probably double-check that.

Note that `std::vector` will use heap memory, so the data will never go into flash memory (aside from an extremely aggressive compiler doing magic), so you probably want a `std::array` instead.

Comment: I didn't get it though: how do I create 3 instances of `config` holding different `config_items`?

Comment: @dymanoid You would need to return a config instead of just the vector. Have you considered going with a `const config` that contains non-`const` `vector`s?